# Rcpp 'candidate function has different number of parameters (expected 0 but has 1)'

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm very new to C++ and Rcpp. I have the following function, which converts a character vector containing string representations of large integers to integers, then converts these to hexadecimals and takes a substring of the resulting hex number. I can use this function with sourceCpp and it generates the expected result.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::StringVector mcc(Rcpp::StringVector  x) {
  unsigned short int n = x.size();
  Rcpp::StringVector output(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    unsigned long int number = std::strtoul(x[i], NULL, 10);
    std::stringstream sstream;
    sstream << std::hex << number;
    std::string result = sstream.str();
    output[i] = result.substr(0,3);
    sstream.str("");
  }
  return output;
}
```

However, when I try to compile the function to include it in a package I'm building, the compiler (clang++, on Mac) throws the following errors:

```
RcppExports.cpp:24:40: error: address of overloaded function 'mcc' does not match required type 'void *()'
{"mcc",                 (DL_FUNC) &mcc,                 1},
                                   ^~~
RcppExports.cpp:20:17: note: candidate function has different number of parameters (expected 0 but has 1)
RcppExport SEXP mcc(SEXP);
                ^
RcppExports.cpp:9:20: note: candidate function has different number of parameters (expected 0 but has 1)
Rcpp::StringVector mcc(Rcpp::StringVector x);
```

My experience with C++ is virtually nonexisting, so I don't even understand what it's saying here. A google/Stackoverflow search for the error message did not return any helpful results.

I appreciate your help!

--- EDIT ----

This is the code generated by compileAttributes() (run twice)

```
// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// mcc
Rcpp::StringVector mcc(Rcpp::StringVector x);
RcppExport SEXP _cropMobileData_mcc(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::StringVector >::type x(xSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(mcc(x));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}

RcppExport SEXP mcc(SEXP);

static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
    {"_cropMobileData_mcc", (DL_FUNC) &_cropMobileData_mcc, 1},
    {"mcc",                 (DL_FUNC) &mcc,                 1},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

RcppExport void R_init_cropMobileData(DllInfo *dll) {
    R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
    R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

Comment: It basically says that `DL_FUNC` is `void *()`, a pointer to a function taking no parameters. The two `mcc` functions the compiler finds take a different number of parameters, so they don't match.

Comment: I added the includes. It should output a vector of strings of length 3

Comment: "when I try to compile the function to include it in a package I'm building" How do you do that? By building the package?

Comment: I hit the "Build package" button in Rstudio :)

Comment: What is the content of your DESCRIPTION file? Have you tried building the package outside RStudio?

Comment: it includes "LinkingTo: Rcpp" if that's what you mean. I haven't tried building outside of Rstudio

Comment: Well, try that. You need to find out what goes wrong during the build process.

Comment: Okay, will do that and get back here with the details

Comment: We would need the code to see.  The issue with the generated glue code; sometimes running `compileAttributes()` _twice_ helps.  This is a transition issue brought to use by R 3.4.* which we addressed in Rcpp 0.12.11 and 0.12.12, but it is not perfect.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I added the output of compileAttributes() (I ran it twice like you said)

Comment: What R version? What Rcpp version?

Comment: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 /R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21); Rcpp  0.12.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine.  Rcpp is perfectly fine.  R is perfectly fine.

But *something* on your system is not, and we cannot tell remotely what the issue is.

Complete log follows.

#### First we create a package

```
edd@brad:/tmp$ Rscript -e 'Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("jeroenclaes")'
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './jeroenclaes/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding Rcpp settings
 >> added Imports: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp
 >> added useDynLib directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp) directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added example src file using Rcpp attributes
 >> added Rd file for rcpp_hello_world
 >> compiled Rcpp attributes
edd@brad:/tmp$ cd jeroenclaes/
```

#### Next we copy your code

```
edd@brad:/tmp/jeroenclaes$
edd@brad:/tmp/jeroenclaes$  ## edit step here copying SO post code
edd@brad:/tmp/jeroenclaes$
```

#### We create the Glue

Note that `compAttr.r` is just a trivial shell wrapper from my littler 
package.  No magic here.  Note that I only ran it once.  (The running twice issue arises sometimes when working with existing packages.)

```
edd@brad:/tmp/jeroenclaes$ compAttr.r
edd@brad:/tmp/jeroenclaes$
```

#### Next we build the package

```
edd@brad:/tmp/jeroenclaes$ cd ..
edd@brad:/tmp$ R CMD build jeroenclaes
* checking for file ‘jeroenclaes/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘jeroenclaes’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to process help pages
* saving partial Rd database
* cleaning src
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building ‘jeroenclaes_1.0.tar.gz’
edd@brad:/tmp$
```

#### And check it

```
edd@brad:/tmp$ R CMD check jeroenclaes_1.0.tar.gz
* using log directory ‘/tmp/jeroenclaes.Rcheck’
* using R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
* using platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file ‘jeroenclaes/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘jeroenclaes’ version ‘1.0’
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package ‘jeroenclaes’ can be installed ... [12s/11s] OK
* checking installed package size ... OK
* checking package directory ... OK
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking top-level files ... OK
* checking for left-over files ... OK
* checking index information ... OK
* checking package subdirectories ... OK
* checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... OK
* checking R files for syntax errors ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking loading without being on the library search path ... OK
* checking dependencies in R code ... OK
* checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK
* checking replacement functions ... OK
* checking foreign function calls ... OK
* checking R code for possible problems ... OK
* checking Rd files ... OK
* checking Rd metadata ... OK
* checking Rd cross-references ... OK
* checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
Undocumented code objects:
  ‘mcc’
All user-level objects in a package should have documentation entries.
See chapter ‘Writing R documentation files’ in the ‘Writing R
Extensions’ manual.
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK
* checking Rd \usage sections ... OK
* checking Rd contents ... OK
* checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
* checking line endings in C/C++/Fortran sources/headers ... OK
* checking compiled code ... OK
* checking examples ... OK
* checking PDF version of manual ... OK
* DONE

Status: 1 WARNING
See
  ‘/tmp/jeroenclaes.Rcheck/00check.log’
for details.


edd@brad:/tmp$
```

Looks just fine to me.

#### For Completeness

```
edd@brad:/tmp$ R CMD INSTALL jeroenclaes_1.0.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘jeroenclaes’ ...
** libs
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -Werror -march=native -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -Werror -march=native -c mcc.cpp -o mcc.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -Werror -march=native -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
ccache g++ -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o jeroenclaes.so RcppExports.o mcc.o rcpp_hello_world.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/jeroenclaes/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (jeroenclaes)
edd@brad:/tmp$ R

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library(jeroenclaes)
> mcc("The quick brown fox")
[1] "0"
>
```

Maybe it is macOS specific. I don't know -- maybe ask on r-sig-mac.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Dirk. I'll try to rebuild the package from scratch, following the steps you provided.

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is customary (even expected) to "accept" a helpful and suitable answer: click on the tickmark (only you see as the person asking it).  You can also "upvote" by clicking on the 'up' triangle.

Comment: Oops, I was unaware of that. I marked your excellent answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error today. My solution is that replace the .Call method by call function by name directly and it magically worked.

Just share my experience with you.